# Tinea Capitis ( Ringworm of the scalp) under a magnifying glass

Tags: dermatology

Supposing a patient has Tinea Capitis (Ringworm of the scalp)  what will you see under a magnifying glass?

Answer (score 2):

Probably nothing diagnostic would be seen using a handheld magnifying lens.  Preferably one would use a microscope but that also has limitations.

> Microscopic examination of the infected hairs may provide immediate confirmation of the diagnosis of ringworm and establishes whether the fungus is small-spore or large-spore ectothrix or endothrix.

https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1091351-workup

Comment: +1: Maybe point out the difference between a magnifying glass (max. 2x magnification) and a microscope (max 1000x magnification, values taken from Wikipedia. Some handheld lenses could go up to 6x, but that’s no match...

Answer (score 0):

You will see hyphae (which produce spores that appear as crusted plaque-likelesions on the scalp)

[HairlossRevolution](https://www.hairlossrevolution.com/fungal-infections/)